# Use HTML5 tags with Bootstrap for a more Semantic website?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup

Having seen the source of one of the [Bootstrap Expo](http://expo.getbootstrap.com/) sites [Tsaa Tea Shop](http://www.tsaateashop.com/) I wonder if what they have done, adding semantic HTML5 tags in between BS classes, would give the site a better semantic value?

Considering they use the [section](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) [element](http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.pdf) quite a bit, can this be seen as an accepted and good use of HTML5 tags/elements alongside BS?

Here a short excerpt:

```
<section class="about-us block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-title">Welcome</h2>

                <span class="fa fa-leaf"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="quote block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>"We loved our relaxing time with great food and beverages..."</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

At the moment I am starting work on a smaller project and have something along the line of a simple one-page layout in mind.

Would it do any good in consideration of semantics to follow this approach?

Comment: BS is orthogonal to semantics. The section elements really aren't adding any new semantics but are harmless. The second h2 appears to be the heading to nothing.

Comment: @Alohci "orthogonal to semantics", do you mean it does not work well with it by saying that? Do not know this expression, sorry.

Comment: I mean independent from. Use of Bootstrap does not affect HTML semantics, for better or worse.

Comment: Thank you. From your opinion a small site like that with more HTML5 tags, like article, aside and so on, that would affect the semantics, no? I mean that is what it is there for, right? So mixing it as good as possible with BS is a good thing, right? What are the other options in terms of semantics? For such a small site BS was not really needed and could have been done with pure HTML5 and CSS3 without any framework and with possibly much more semantic properties. Is that what you are thinking? Curious to hear opinions or how to follow semantic markup well.

Comment: Think layers. Write your HTML using semantic elements where appropriate. When that is in place, use CSS (via bootstrap if you so wish) to layer the styling over the top of your semantic HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Bootstrap is unsemantic by default

Twitter Bootstrap is one of the most **unsemantic** frameworks on the market. If you put to your code classes like `container`, `form-control` or `col-sm-2` you just can't be semantic.

**But sometimes you don't want to be.** You want to be readable, practical and maintainable — and that's why it is made for and it's great in it.

### HTML5 tags

Yes, yes. We have all these new, sexy, useful, years-needed HTML5 tags like: `article`, `section`, `nav`, `main`, `header`, `footer` or `details`… **But let's face truth — the `section` sucks almost as much as usuall `div`.**

[Semantic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/semantic) of the `section` is almost zero. God - it's a tag with `display:block` that **is called "section"**. The biggest (and maybe only) advantage of it is improving of readability, not the semantics. And that's enough.

### Why to still use the new HTML tags

Because:

1. It's more readable.
2. It's easier to debug.
3. It's more modern.
4. It's a bit more meaningful and consequential.

So, if you face the decision — **to use or not to use HTML5 tags**, do anything, but do not continue in this **div-cancer-that-is-the-web-built-on**.

… even minified version of new tags is more readable:

```html
<article><section></section><section></section><aside></aside></article>
<div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: bootstrap haters with the downvotes - @Samuel Ondrek is correct - look at that example. divisitus out the wazoo - also, bootstrap is horrible for accessibility - the real irony here is caring about such things, while using bootstrap

Comment: @Samuel Ondrek Thank you for your answer!! I will definitely take that into consideration when writing Bootstrap code the next time.Do you know or any or THE most semantic or with regards to accessibility decent/solid framework that packs a responsive grid and perhaps a responsive navigation into its toolbox? Happy to write my own grid if must be and use better semantics and better code with regards to accessibility. Should this be done for small sites like the one mentioned? What is a good approach here? Any info is MOST welcome. Thank you. :)